# The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid when calling Access Token API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token

Hello I am getting the below error.

AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'user.read%20mail.read' does not exist.\r\nTrace ID: 5c5ced96-67a8-4c02-8b24-755e69b07f00\r\nCorrelation ID: 36d8e66d-fbf8-454d-95d6-0a0ad5f70836\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-06 11:46:44Z

I am calling Auth URL

https://login.microsoftonline.com/Common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=#####&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63135/Account/MicrosoftCode&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345

I am successfully getting code on the redirect URl. But when I am calling the access token post url I am getting an error.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

[image]

Below is Token URL response

{
"error": "invalid_scope",
"error_description": "AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'user.read%20mail.read' does not exist.\r\nTrace ID: 5c5ced96-67a8-4c02-8b24-755e69b07f00\r\nCorrelation ID: 36d8e66d-fbf8-454d-95d6-0a0ad5f70836\r\nTimestamp: 2022-10-06 11:46:44Z",
"error_codes": [
70011
],
"timestamp": "2022-10-06 11:46:44Z",
"trace_id": "5c5ced96-67a8-4c02-8b24-755e69b07f00",
"correlation_id": "36d8e66d-fbf8-454d-95d6-0a0ad5f70836"
}

I added below permissions in my Azure account.

[image]

Can you please help, what I am doing wrong. The postman is working fine, I have to implement on c#.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** and granted the API permissions:

[image]

I generated the **code** successfully with the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirect_url
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read mail.read
&state=12345
```

[image]

To generate the **access token via Postman**, please make use of below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:client_id
redirect_uri:redirect_url
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:user.read mail.read
code:code
client_secret:******
```

To resolve the error `AADSTS70011`, try replacing the **scope** parameter as **`user.read mail.read`**.

***I am able to generate access token successfully like below:***

[image]

To generate the access token via **`Authorization_Code`** flow using c#, please make use of the below sample code:

```cs
AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
            IEnumerable<string> scopes,
            string authorizationCode)
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddAzureAD(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

*For complete code, please **refer** this* [**GitHub Blog**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible parameter sequence has problem? I didn't see refresh_token parameter in Json response. Did you see in your response?

Comment: To get refresh_token in response, make sure to include offline_access in scope while generating the token.

Comment: Done. Thanks for quick help and resolved mine issue.